# console.log wrapper with color and line number

Tags: javascript, console

I start with this :

```
function l(...message) {

if(message[0].includes('success')){
         color = 'Green';
         console.log(`%c${message}`, `color:${color};font-weight:bold;`);
    }else{
         console.log(...message);
    }
}
```

It work but I lost line number.
[image]
So I try this :

```
l = function(m) {
    return Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console, `%c${m}`,'font-weight:bold;');
}();
```

It keep the good line number, but don't work as expected...

**What I want is being able to color my log and keep the correct line , in different color according the message**

Comment: You changed the code to an IEFE, but kept the `m` parameter, which is getting passed no argument - `m` is `undefined`. You cannot put it inside a string using only `bind`.

Comment: I know, I could add a prefix if I define the m
What I want is being able to color my log and keep the correct line

Comment: Probably something like `console.log.bind(console, "%c%s", "…")` would do it - not using a template literal, but relying on the interpolation capabilities of `console.log` itself.

Comment: Ok @Bergi , it does the trick but ... how could I add conditional on the message :
For example if message include success --> color is green, if error color is red ...?

Comment: Well, you can't. Neither `bind` nor the interpolation syntax of `console.log` support that.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires some weirdness when called, but provides all the functionality you need... Create a function that returns a function, something like this:

```js
function output(message) {
  if (isProduction) {
    return function(){};
  }

  if (message.includes('success')) {
    message = colors.green(message);
  }

  return console.log.bind(console, message);
}
```

This example assumes a couple of things...

1. You have some global variable `isProduction` which is set to `true` if this is a production environment (where you don't want anything output). This is just to provide an example of how this logic can be used to prevent output in certain situations (for example, I have a "todo" method which ensures a particular todo message is only ever output once).
2. You are using some library (`colors` in this example) to wrap your text in color codes.

This wrapper function must have any parameters that will impact the logic of what you want to output. It returns a function which you then call (you can of course pass additional parameters to that returned function, and they will get added to the output, but generally probably simpler to have the wrapper function handle all parameters).

So you might call it like this (note that additional "`()`" at the end)...

```js
output("HTML import success!")();
```